# cell2mat: padding using NaNs

Tags: matlab

Working mostly in 2 dimensions with cell arrays this probably is a familiar topic to you:

```
a{1,1}=rand(5,1);
a{2,1}=rand(10,1);
b=cell2mat(a);
size(b)
```

the output of which will be the size of `[15 1]`. However I would find an example outcome like this more useful:

```
0.150   0.340   0.610   0.190   0.740   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
0.240   0.920   0.270   0.770   0.190   0.290   0.090   0.580   0.680   0.550
```

Is there a generalized way of padding cellarrays with NaNs (in a similar way as above) so they can be converted to matrices easily?

As there is a lot of confusion here's graphically (please excuse my handdrawing skills) what I mean, where 1,2 depict cell arrays and 3 is the NaN padding. 1,2,3 combined hould be easily convertable to a matrix.

[image]

Comment: Don't you mean `[30 2]`? So, you want a regular matrix as the output, right?

Comment: what output do you expect if there are more than 1 columns in `a`

Comment: Think you need to further clarify how's that nan padding to be done. Also, the expected output for cells with more than 1 column as asked earlier.

Comment: sorry for this, adapted question

Comment: How about cells with more than 1 column? Or did you mean the cell array would be 2D, while each cell would always have one column? That `Working mostly in 2 dimensions` needs clarification I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% find the long vector
isLong=(length(a{2,1})>length(a{1,1}))+1;
isShort=setdiff([1 2],isLong);

% result
b=[a{isLong,1}  [a{isShort,1};nan(length(a{isLong,1})-length(a{isShort,1}),1)]]



b =

0.0796    0.6440
0.7326    0.4967
0.5137    0.9919
0.5223    0.7241
0.8144    0.3799
0.8346       NaN
0.9469       NaN
0.4866       NaN
0.1802       NaN
0.1786       NaN
```